# css is not loading in multi STORE VIEW magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, store-view

I've set up multi-store view with multi language, but I'm facing a weird issue that is default store view is running perfectly but another store view is not able to load CSS.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the network tab in developer tools you'll need to see what are the files missing'404'

I think you'll need to deploy statics considering the languages/locales you use in these store views

ex. you've locales `en_GB`, `es_ES`

for deploying statics you should use the command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB es_ES`

Comment: i have tried this but still the same issue

Comment: can you share the path for the missing files please?

Comment: i checked in my local server

Comment: a screenshot if possible for the file paths even from local, need to check what are the missing files

Comment: localhost/magento/esp/